# Use same DATABASE_NAME and TABLE_NAME for multiple apps

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

So, I am doing the old copy/paste of working code for multiple apps that will find their way on the same phone.  Can I copy/paste my SQLite helper classes without changing the database and table names?  Is there risk of the tables and databases "cross pollinating"?  Of course, each app has a unique package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this risk does not exist. If you search for the db files into android file system you can see that they resides in different folders. Now I don't remember where they are, but you can do a simple research